RCTAppDelegate::bundleURL not implemented', reason: 'Subclasses must implement a valid getBundleURL method'
I am trying to add Expo to a bare React Native project. I have upgraded to RN 0.74.2 and EXPO SDK 51. When I run "npx expo run:ios" the app opens but immediately crashed with the following

Opening org.reactjs.native.example.OnSight on iPhone 15 Pro
[CoreFoundation] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTAppDelegate::bundleURL not implemented', reason: 'Subclasses must implement a valid getBundleURL method'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae138 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180087db4 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804ae048 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   OnSight                             0x0000000100a33418 -[RCTAppDelegate bundleURL] + 52
4   OnSight                             0x00000001002c2350 -[EXAppDelegateWrapper createRCTRootViewFactory] + 52
5   OnSight                             0x0000000100a3270c -[RCTAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 176
6   OnSight                             0x00000001002c2204 -[EXAppDelegateWrapper application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 104
7   OnSight                             0x000000010026345c -[AppDelegate application:didFinish<…>

I have deeleted cache, node_modules, yarn.lock, metro cache, Pods and Podfile.lock

I have updated the AppDelegate.mm with the following code and it resolved the issue.
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@".expo/.virtual-metro-entry"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}


Dude, you're a genius! I've been struggling with this as well!

genius man, it took me many days, thanks a lot mate <3<3<3

This is crazy. I had - (NSURL *)getBundleURL  changing to bundleURL it just work. Any reason for this? ah found it: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.73.6&to=0.74.5
